# Unable to list all api endpoints in swagger file in django and drf spectacular

Tags: python, django, swagger, drf-spectacular

Unable to list all api endpoints in swagger file. API endpoints are working as expected wrt functionalities. I'm using py3 and gunicorn as I need this deployed.

Settings.py of djServer project has all req settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema'  
}


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_spectacular',  
    'corsheaders',
    'djApi',
    'djBookings',
    'sample',
]

#djServer/djServer/urls.py
"""
URL configuration for djServer project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from drf_spectacular.views import(
    SpectacularAPIView,
    SpectacularSwaggerView,
)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('help/Schema/',SpectacularAPIView.as_view(),name='help-schema'),
    path('help/Docs/',SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='help-schema'),name='help-docs'),
    path('sampleApi/', include('sample.urls')),
    path('api/', include('djApi.urls')),
    path('bookings/', include('djBookings.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

While the project has many djnago apps where url is in this form

```
# djServer/bookings/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('testEndpoint/', bookingsTest, name='bookingsTest'),
    path('freeTrial/', freeTrial, name='freeTrial'),
    path('availFreeTrial/<str:booking_id>', availFreeTrial, name='availFreeTrial'),
    # Add more paths as needed
]
```

Swagger page shows only one endpoint
[image]

Comment: Have you decorated your endpoints with the `@extend_schema` decorator?

Comment: Hey @AshleyH. no I didn't add this. U mean I should add this above the endpoint functions in view.py of apps. ?

Comment: I tried adding but no help. Can u once try this locally with production mode with gunicorn ?